I get error at step: createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction, failed: incorrect program id for instruction
error
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Create',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize',
    'Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 884 of 394635 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: incorrect program id for instruction',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 6249 of 400000 compute units',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: incorrect program id for instruction'


Client code.
  const secretKeyString = await fs.readFile(PROGRAM_KEYPAIR_PATH, {encoding: 'utf8'});
  const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(secretKeyString));
  const programKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
  let programId: PublicKey = programKeypair.publicKey;

  const transaction = new web3.Transaction()

const triggersecretKeyString = await fs.readFile(trigger_PROGRAM_KEYPAIR_PATH, {encoding: 'utf8'});
const triggersecretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(triggersecretKeyString));
const triggerKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(triggersecretKey);


  console.log('--LAMPORTS_PER_SOL ', LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);

  const movie = new Movie("aaaa", 5, "description", triggerKeypair.publicKey)
  const buffer = movie.serialize(0)

  const [pda] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [triggerKeypair.publicKey.toBuffer(), Buffer.from(movie.title)], // new TextEncoder().encode(movie.title)],
    programId)

const [pdaCounter] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [pda.toBuffer(), Buffer.from("comment")], // new TextEncoder().encode(movie.title)],
    programId
)
const [tokenMint] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [Buffer.from("token_mint")],
  programId
)

const [mintAuth] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [Buffer.from("token_auth")],
  programId
)


const userAta = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(tokenMint, triggerKeypair.publicKey, false)
const ataAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(userAta)

if (!ataAccount) {
  const ataInstruction = createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
      triggerKeypair.publicKey,
      userAta,
      triggerKeypair.publicKey,
      tokenMint
  )

  //await connection.confirmTransaction(ataInstruction);
  transaction.add(ataInstruction)
}

await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [triggerKeypair],
);


Please help to fix it.

Can you share your transaction ID so the we can see full logs and pinpoint where and what went wrong?

This is a shot in the dark, but GetAccountDataSize on SPL Token only takes in the mint. If it's giving an IncorrectProgramId error, then the mint account you're providing is not an SPL Token mint.
Be sure to initialize tokenMint as an SPL token mint before trying to create accounts for it.

Thanks for your reply, I forgot to initialize tokenMint, and after initializing tokenMint the issue was resolved.
